# Axis One click Connection Component

Tags: ip-camera

We are using axis one click connection component for auto discovery of axis cameras in our surveillance services. The version of the one-click component we are using is 1.2. Is it the latest version or there is a new release? We are basically having trouble getting the RTSP streams connected through one-click component.

Answer (score -1):

Got it. The latest version of [one click component is 1.4.3](http://www.axis.com/partner_pages/software_sdk.php?t=cv&mid=2609)